# Saxon loads slowly in Apache Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, saxon

I am using Saxon in a Tomcat project. The first time Saxon is used, I experience a long delay, 10 seconds. It is possible that I do not have the Saxon JAR or the Saxon license in the best place.

I have put the Saxon license in the Tomcat lib dir. (with the CATALINA and Tomcat JARs). I have put the Saxon JAR in my web app's `WEB-INF/lib` dir.

I am using Apache Tomcat 7.0.65, Java 1.7.0_80, Saxon EE 9.7.0.5, Windows 10.

1. How can I tell how long it takes Saxon to load the first time? vague question.
2. The project is a Maven project, so the `WEB-INF/lib` dir has 139 JARs.
3. Where should the Saxon JAR and license be placed?

**NEW INFORMATION 1 JUNE 2017**

Would it help to supply a stack trace? A partial listing of the slow area is this:

```
14,772 ms net.sf.saxon.jaxp.SaxonTransformerFactory.newTemplates(javax‌​.xml.transform.Sourc‌​e)
14,772 ms net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler.compile(Source)
...
11,429 ms net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.NumberInstruction.simplify()
11,429 ms net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.NumberInstruction.preallocatNumbe‌​rer(Configuration)
11,429 ms makeNumberer()
11,429 ms getNumberer()
11,336 ms JavaPlatformPE.hasICUNumberer()
...
11,305 ms com.ibm.icu.text.RuleBasedCollater.<clinit>
...
11,180 ms Class.getResourceAsStre
```

**More Info on June 2**

`Class.forName("com.ibm.icu.text.RuleBasedNumberFormat");`
takes very little time

Using Class.forName just before the call to newTemplates() does not help.

`com.saxonica.config.ICULibrary.hasNumberer()` returns true

icu4j-49.1.jar is in the classpath

`new com.saxonica.config.ICULibrary();`  takes 10 seconds

Comment: What about `Class.forName("com.ibm.icu.text.RuleBasedCollator")?`

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading Saxon by using the JAXP `TransformerFactory.newInstance()` method? That involves a search of the classpath which can be very time-consuming with 139 JARs on the classpath. Consider instantiating by nominating the Saxon TransformerFactory directly, e.g.

```
TransformerFactory f = new com.saxonica.config.EnterpriseTransformerFactory();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Will look into it.

Comment: Would it help to supply a stack trace?  A partial listing of the slow area is this:

14,772 ms  net.sf.saxon.jaxp.SaxonTransformerFactory.newTemplates(javax.xml.transform.Source)
14,772 ms net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler.compile(Source)
...
11,429 ms  net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.NumberInstruction.simplify()
11,429 ms  net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.NumberInstruction.preallocatNumberer(Configuration)
11,429 ms  makeNumberer()
11,429 ms  getNumberer()
11,336 ms JavaPlatformPE.hasICUNumberer()
...
11,305 ms  com.ibm.icu.text.RuleBasedCollater.<clinit>
...
11,180 ms Class.getResourceAsStre

Comment: Thanks for that information, I have copied it into the question as it's not really a comment on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the new information supplied, the delay occurs when compiling an `xsl:number` instruction, and in particular, when loading the ICU library which Saxon-EE uses for localization support. Saxon is doing a dynamic load on the classes `com.ibm.icu.text.RuleBasedCollator` and  `com.ibm.icu.text.RuleBasedNumberFormat`, which should be found in saxon9-icu.jar if that's on the classpath, or in a different version of the ICU4j library if you've got a different version around. If the class can't be found, Saxon continues without it, but with reduced localization support.

So, for some reason the call on Class.getResourceAsStream() when loading this class appears to be chronically slow. I don't know why, but hopefully this will narrow the investigation. Things to check are (a) whether the load is actually succeeding (call the static method `com.saxonica.config.ICULibrary.hasNumberer()` to find out); (b) whether the ICU libraries are on the classpath, either as issued in the Saxon distribution or otherwise; and then (c) do some loader tracing, perhaps simply doing

```
Class.forName("com.ibm.icu.text.RuleBasedNumberFormat")
```

without involving Saxon at all.